# Apache-camel-cxf - component - Invalid character issue

Tags: yaml, apache-camel, cxf, dsl

I am trying to consume a soap web services using apache camel cxf component with payload as a dataformat once the response is received using jaxb i am unmarshalling to required java class it is working as expected when the response contains utf-8 character set but suddenly response from web services contains some xml reserved characters like & so it is throwing a error?

The stack strace is

2023-05-03 19:36:27.263 ERROR 40201 --- [ult-workqueue-1] o.a.c.p.e.DefaultErrorHandler : Failed delivery for (MessageId: F3FE15DE03B7527-0000000000000000 on ExchangeId: F3FE15DE03B7527-0000000000000000). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException: Error during type conversion from type: org.apache.camel.converter.jaxb.NonXmlFilterReader to the required type: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader with value org.apache.camel.converter.jaxb.NonXmlFilterReader@6958df8b due to com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxLazyException: [com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxLazyException] Illegal character entity: expansion character (code 0x2

I have explained above